# Calling a function with an ID to edit

Tags: javascript, html

This is what i am working with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/k5rh3du0/

I need to call a function with an onLoad and onerror tag with an image.

```
    <img src="http://www.etreeblog.com/favicon.ic0" alt="status" onerror="javascript:offline(blog)" onLoad="javascript:online(blog)"/>

    <img src="http://www.etreestore.com/favicon.ic0" alt="status" onerror="javascript:offline(store)" onLoad="javascript:online(store)"/>

<script>
    offline(site){
        document.getElementById((site)).style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    }
    online(site){
        document.getElementById((site)).style.backgroundColor = "Green";
    }
   </script>
    <div style="background-color:Orange;" id="site">
        Site
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:Orange;" id="blog">
        Blog
    </div>
```

Using something like this.

How can i get this to work?
-The images will have the visibility:hidden; css.

Comment: Start by looking at your JavaScript console and reading the error messages.

Comment: I dont see **function**

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your code are shown in the `Uncaught ReferenceErrors`.

```
 offline(site){
        document.getElementById((site)).style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    }
    online(site){
        document.getElementById((site)).style.backgroundColor = "Green";
    }
```

Notably, `offline(site)` and `online(site)` should be syntactically declared as functions, as shown below. I tried to fix some of the code errors:

```
 function offline(site){
        document.getElementById(site).style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    }
 function   online(site){
        document.getElementById(site).style.backgroundColor = "Green";
    }
```

Also, I don't see `id="store"` and `id="blog"` declared anywhere in your HTML DOM.

Furthermore, even though I'm not sure that it's incorrect, `javascript:` does not have to be used in inline events.

The function `onerror` itself, however, is used correctly.

I recommend that you would pay more attention to the JavaScript console in the future, where you can catch most of your syntax errors.

Mark this answer with the checkmark next to it if it helped you in any manner.

Comment: Could you take a look at this, and see why it's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/k5rh3du0/5/

Comment: Did you read my answer? You're calling (through `document.getElementById`) `store` and `blog`, but they are not declared.